# How I can create a link to page from template?

Tags: magento2, frontend

I would like to generate a link like this:

```
<a href="http://example.com/my-custom-page">My link</a>
```

Target page: **example.com/my-custom-page**.

Template: `module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml`

Comment: U need to use custom `Router.php` or make Controller file will needed path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, use cms page to create new page with identifier is `your_custom_page_link`.

In your phtml file, use this code: `<a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('your_custom_page_link') ?>">Link label</a>`

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add dependency in your related block

```
    public $_storeManager;
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
       .....
    ) {
       ...
       $this->_storeManager=$storeManager;
    }
    public function getCustomUrl($customUrl){
      return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl() . $customUrl;
    }
```

Add in your template below code:

```
echo $block->getCustomUrl('my-custom-page');
```

Comment: hi ,@Prashant, how can i pass argument to template file without appending it tot the Browser Url

Answer (score 0):

get url key of your page :
[image]

and put it in your href

```
<a href="url_key_of_your_page"></a>
```